# How to get the second word on each line with regex?

Tags: php, regex

I have the following output (string variable) with process lists:

```
chrome.exe                    1680 RDP-Tcp#0                  1    104,552 K
chrome.exe                    8944 RDP-Tcp#0                  1    133,680 K
csrss.exe                     8880 Console                   19      3,796 K
winlogon.exe                  6728 Console                   19      4,484 K
LogonUI.exe                   9024 Console                   19     19,552 K
dwm.exe                      11476 Console                   19     19,916 K
rdpclip.exe                   8152 RDP-Tcp#0                  1      8,240 K
```

How can I extract all PIDs using regex (PHP)?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this pattern:

```
preg_match_all('~^\S+\s+\K\d+~m', $subject, $matches);
print_r($matches);
```

`\K` resets all the match before.

Comment: Thanks, very elegant solution.

Answer (score 3):

try: `[^\d]*(\d+).*\n?`

group 1 can get every first digit on each line.

Comment: It's a good idea too! You can remove the first and last part: `(\d+).*` (don't forget the last line, that has no newline after.)

Comment: thank you for your reminding, I've added `?` after `\n`, @Casimir et Hippolyte

Comment: As I said in my precedent comment, you can remove the last `\n` since the dot doesn't match it an since you use a possessive quantifier before.

Comment: thanks again, right, we can make it shorter by just using `[^\d]*(\d+).*`    :)

Comment: Thanks; I like the shortness of this.

Comment: ERRATUM: you must read: "since you use a greedy quantifier" (not a possessive quantifier.)

Answer (score 2):

`/^[^\s]+\s+([0-9]+)/m` should work fine:

```
<?php
    $string = "
chrome.exe                    1680 RDP-Tcp#0                  1    104,552 K
chrome.exe                    8944 RDP-Tcp#0                  1    133,680 K
csrss.exe                     8880 Console                   19      3,796 K
winlogon.exe                  6728 Console                   19      4,484 K
LogonUI.exe                   9024 Console                   19     19,552 K
dwm.exe                      11476 Console                   19     19,916 K
rdpclip.exe                   8152 RDP-Tcp#0                  1      8,240 K
    ";

    if (preg_match_all("/^[^\s]+\s+([0-9]+)/m", $string, $matches)) {
        print_r($matches[1]);
        /*
            Array
            (
                [0] => 1680
                [1] => 8944
                [2] => 8880
                [3] => 6728
                [4] => 9024
                [5] => 11476
                [6] => 8152
            )
        */
    }
?>
```

[**PHP DEMO**](https://eval.in/56718)

**Regex autopsy**:

- `^` - *The string match MUST start here (since we use the `/m` modifier, then this means that every line MUST start with what comes after this character)*
- `[^\s]+` - *Any character that isn't a space/tab/newline repeated 1 or more times*
- `\s+` - *Any character that is a space/tab/newline repeated 1 or more times*
- `([0-9]+)` - *A capturing group matching the numbers from `0` to `9` repeated 1 or more times*
- `/m` - *our modifier - This means that `^` will match the start of every line and not the entire text*